# Ajax form submit not sending file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, upload

I try to implement an upload script using ajax/jquery witch will upload my selected file without page refresh and without submiting the form.
I have designed the form, and made the script but when i monitorize using Firebug->network shows me that on post send all the inputs without file input.

this is my html:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="Form_extract_type_sdf100" id="sdf100" value="0">

        <div class="load-area">
<input type="file" name="file" id="mainimage" class="file-upload" />
<h1>Main Image</h1>
<div class='main-image' id='mainimg'>

</div>
```

The input file is hidden and is triggered when i hit on div main-image:

```
    $('#mainimg').click(function(event) {
    $('#mainimage').click();
});
```

After that i have the event change for the input file:

```
        $("input:file").change(function (){
    $("#insertadd").submit();
});
```

And then then the submit event:

```
    $('#insertadd').submit(function(e){
                   e.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh
                   var form = $('#insertadd').serialize();
                   //submit.php is the page where you submit your form
                   $.post('/it/controllare', form, function(data){ 


                   });
              });
```

I'm working on laravel an the url /it/controllare is correct.
So does anyone have any ideea why mi hidden fields are send and i get them in $_POST and the file is not?

Comment: You're going to have a really hard time uploading files with ajax. The easiest thing you can do is download a library that will do it for you but is quite heavy. I'd advice you to go with ordinary http requests for file uploads.

Comment: I use this jQuery library and it works great. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: To add to @php_nub_qq's comment: you can stay on the page by uploading to an iframe.

Comment: You have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to `form`?